# Showing "Please buy" screen to pirates

Tags: legal, publishing, commercial

*I recently saw [this](http://www.greenheartgames.com/2013/04/29/what-happens-when-pirates-play-a-game-development-simulator-and-then-go-bankrupt-because-of-piracy/) and [this](http://kotaku.com/5955478/what-works-better-drm-or-just-being-nice-to-pirates), and that got me thinking*

When publishing a commercial game without DRM, would it be a good idea to upload a slightly modified copy of the game that shows a screen like this at startup to, say, The Pirate Bay:

> Hello pirate! Looks like you downloaded this game from The Pirate Bay! That's okay, but:
>   Making a game costs time and money. If you like the game, please buy it so we can continue to update this game with new content! You buy it for only $xx.xx at www.example.com!
>
> In the meantime: Have fun!
>
> *Press Enter to continue*

And then continues to the title screen and from there is identical to a legal copy.

The point is that it will probably (very, very, VERY high chance that it will) be uploaded sooner or later anyway, so this may decrease the harm.

Would that be a good idea?

Comment: I think there is no definite answer to this question, however I feel this is quite pointless. I've seen it in movies too, where they show a short video that says downloading this movie is like stealing a car, your wouldn't do that would you? I think most people will ignore this and just take it as an ignorable annoyance.
I think it's best to make a player login to the game when playing  multiplayer mode (and if you will also singleplayer). Off course, with a non purchased version this wouldn't work. It seems more effective to me.

Comment: Well, for one thing its good marketing, people talk about it when they wouldnt without that move. If the game is good, then its gonna be there anyway, those guys seem to understand that and make the best out of it. At least the have publicity.

Comment: If there was any reliable way to identify pirate users only, then you could just disable the game instead of putting up an annoying ignorable message. You are begging eh question here.

Comment: @Thomas This is only showing it to people who pirated it; not to everyone. Made that even more clear now.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It's not identifying them, it's uploading a modified version with this screen to a site like The Pirate Bay. Which bought copies doesn't contain. The point is that it will probably (very, very, VERY high chance that it will) be uploaded sooner or later anyway, so this may decrease the harm. If you upload a non-functioning copy to TPB like you say, well someone else will upload a functioning one. With the message-method this may happen as well, but the chance is smaller. It's just about trying to decrease harm.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I wouldn't call it pirating to download a game from TPB which the developer released for free by uploading it there himself.

Comment: For what price are you selling the game? I'm thinking of this: you offer a free version with limited content at first. You can upgrade to the full version either by buying or by donating to, say greenpeace or msf.org. You won't be earning more by this, but at least you could appeal at their good conscience.

Comment: @msell That's a pretty good point from a legal standpoint, but, I think it will not make any difference in practise. While illegal, there is no punishment for pirating (at least not in my country). Illegal or not, people will pirate it.

Comment: True. However if you give the product away for free on TPB, other's might be allowed to legally redistribute it through any other channels as well. And it's not nice to call users pirates in the startup in such case. Also note that what you are suggesting would probably violate [The Pirate Bay's Usage policy](http://thepiratebay.sx/policy).

Comment: @msell Can't read it without a proxy (TPB is censored in my country), which I can't connect to at the moment (Will do when I come home), but, It has a policy? Something illegal has a policy? Lol?

Comment: @Jop There's nothing illegal about The Pirate Bay, just like there's nothing illegal about a computer. However, both can be *used for illegal things*.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a good answer for this kind of question. Generally "Should I?" questions depend on your personal preference. If you want to include the screen go ahead, but software pirates will only see it if they download the version you put online. If someone puts up the copy they paid for most likely you won't be able to easily detect if they are a pirate or not (unless you have like a login system or something).

Answer (score 14):

If it's a good idea or not is up to you. And the success of the strategy depends on what your actual goal is.

No Time to Explain did this *way back* in 2011. They [uploaded a special version of the game to Pirate Bay](http://torrentfreak.com/indie-game-devs-post-pirated-game-on-the-pirate-bay-110909/) that had all the characters wearing pirate hats.

> “We thought it’d be funny to leak a pirate version ourselves which is
>   literally all about pirates and pirate hats,” Alex told TorrentFreak.
>   “I mean, some people are going to torrent it either way, we might as
>   well make something funny out of it.”

[image]

It's unknown if the strategy of creating a special version just for pirates gets more pirates to buy the game instead of pirate it. However, it's been shown in the past to improve the media coverage of the game, potentially drawing more legitimate users. The developers of No Time to Explain said:

> “We saw very positive WTF REALLY feedback from users, and saw
>   reactions that people bought it simply because they liked the joke. So
>   we don’t see it hurting sales in any way,” Alex said.

However, it's unclear if this strategy only works for games that were already popular, or if a fairly unknown game could be boosted into the spotlight with this method. Further, this strategy likely has limited uses. It's only been successful because it's somewhat unique and interesting. If every game does this, it's not as interesting and news sites stop reporting on it.

You could opt for a more subtle approach of just including a message for *everyone*, telling them you've worked hard on the game and you appreciate their purchase of the game. Something like what [S.P.A.Z.](http://www.spacepiratesandzombies.com/) did:

[image]

There are a number of approaches to marketing and getting your game more widely known. There isn't any evidence (as far as I know) of any strategies that effectively convert pirates into paying customers. **So, if your intention of doing this is for marketing, then sure, it's worth a try, but if it's solely an attempt to convert pirates, you're not likely to have much success.**